# Change link target attribute if its href attribute contains certain phrase

Tags: jquery-selectors, if-statement, target, jquery

I am trying to check all anchors' tags using `.each()` and set home URLs' target to `_self` and other non-home URLs' target to `_blank`.

So far, I got this:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var homeURL = 'google.ca';    
    if ( $(this+'[href*='+homeURL+']')) {
        $(this).attr('target','_self');
    }else{
        $(this).attr('target','_blank');
    }  
});
```

This is also on jsBin [here](http://jsbin.com/inifov).

For some reason, the non-home URLs set to `target="_self"`. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
if($(this).is("[href*=" + homeURL + "]")){
    $(this).attr('target','_self');
} else {
    $(this).attr('target','_blank');
}
```

[`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns `true` if the selected element matches the selector in the function and `false` if it does not. So, if the current link's `href` [attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) `google.ca`, it'll change its `target` attribute to `_self`. Otherwise, it'll set it to `_blank`.

And, in fact, for more efficiency, you should cache `$(this)`:

```
var $this = $(this);
if($this.is("[href*=" + homeURL + "]")){
    $this.attr('target','_self');
} else {
    $this.attr('target','_blank');
}
```

Comment: Thnx! Nice, I am starting to love this website! I already asked three questions, today is the first day I started posting questions, and in short time they got answered. Awesome website with awesome people in it!

Comment: @FoxKllD: No problem. That's the idea with the site! I love being on here to help my fellow programmers. :) I'd like to point out that if my answer helped you in solving your problem, that it is good practice to mark it as accepted for future visitors.

Comment: I was trying to mark it every minute and at fifth I finally could mark your answer! LoL, I think my problem was that I didn't know the problem.

Comment: All we're doing is storing `$(this)` in the variable whose name is `$this`. What that does is let us use `$(this)` just once. Since it's an expensive selector (it's pretty slow, and will noticeably reduce the page's speed if used too much), it's best to use it as little as possible.

Answer (score 7):

```
var homeURL = 'google.ca';
$('a').each(function() {        
    $(this).attr('target', (this.href.match( homeURL )) ? '_self' :'_blank');       
});
```

Comment: Thnx man! You showed me another way of doing what I wanted to do. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Very nice, elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[href^='http']").attr('target','_blank');
});
```